# Click Counter with javascript

Tags: javascript

This is me trying to create a like counter and display the number of clicks above the image. However i seem to get it to work if i target only the class without looping through it. But i need the looping because i got the same class over other items. `.querySelectorAll` is returning the correct number of click inside the console but not displaying it even though i specified `.innerHTML`

```js
// heart animation when we click on it    
$('.like-btn').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
});

//click counter
var like_button = document.querySelectorAll('.like-btn'),
count = 0;  
for (var i = 0; i < like_button.length; i++) {
   like_button.onclick = function(){
  count += 1;
  like_button.innerHTML = "" + count;
  console.log(like_button)
    }
};
```

```css
.like-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-self: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: url('twitter-heart.png');
  Cursor: pointer;
  background-size: 2900%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 5;
}

.is-active {
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: .8s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: steps(28);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    background-position: left;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: right;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="like-btn"></div>
```

i suspect that `nodelist` is preventing this to work properly and i should use `.foreach`?

Comment: Why are you messing around with querySelectorAll and a loop in “vanilla” JavaScript, when you are apparently using jQuery already?

Comment: just used jquery for the hearth animation. the rest of my code uses no library

Comment: also trying to learn, i don't see anything wrong with that

Comment: Although you are looping over the _number_ of elements, you did not actually access a specific element inside your loop, you are still trying to add the click handler to the result of querySelectorAll: `like_button.onclick` - that would need to be `like_button[i].onclick` for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll(".like-btn").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", () => {
    count++
    el.innerText = count
    console.log(el)
}))
```

You can't add an event listener to a NodeList, you need to target an individual element.

Comment: Thanks. I was close with the thinking but still. It's a good lesson.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are trying to call onclick and innerHtml on an array of elements rather than an element itself. Try changing those references as follows:
`like_button[i].onClick()` etc.

E.g.,

```
//click counter
var like_buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.like-btn'),
count = 0;  
for (var i = 0; i < like_button.length; i++) {
   like_buttons[i].onclick = function(){
  count += 1;
  like_buttons[i].innerHTML = "" + count;
  console.log(like_buttons[i])
    }
};
```

Try that.